# extract colored region

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I want to extract each colored region in MATLAB after applying SRM segmentation method on a particular image.

I tried the following, but it seems that it extracts regions with different color (not the same color degree only), and with the largest area.

```
I = imread('./img/bfly.jpg');
imshow(I)

bw = im2bw(I);
imshow(bw)

L = bwlabel(bw);
imshow(L == 0)

props = regionprops(L);
[~,ind] = max([props.Area]);
imshow(L == ind);
```

Is there a way to extract each color separately?

This is an example image. I want to extract the brown color alone, the green color alone, and so on ...

[image]

Comment: @chappjc : I do not want to extract the brown color only , I want to extract every color and show each part in separated window

Comment: What are the 3 last lines for? This code choses the object with the largest area. Did you copy it from somewhere?

Comment: @user2752385 I see.  Try my updated answer.  It works for the image you attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your image appears to have no smooth variations of color, it should be straightforward to separate the colors into different images with `unique` to convert the image to label matrix (you could do this with `rgb2ind` also) followed by `accumarray`:

```
[Iu,ia,iu] = unique(reshape(I,[],3),'rows');
counts = accumarray(iu,1);
[counts,sortinds] = sort(counts,'descend');
```

Now say you want the `N` largest components:

```
N = 10;
largestLabels = sortinds(1:N);
```

Then the image for color `ii`:

```
mapi = reshape(iu == largestLabels(ii),size(I,1),size(I,2));
numeli = counts(ii)
```

The corresponding RGB values and the number of pixels of each color:

```
>> colorRegionSummary = [uint32(Iu(largestLabels,:)) counts(1:N)]
colorRegionSummary =
     89    120     23   8206  % green
     73     59     42   4370  % dark brown (wing)
     64    128    184   2723  % blue (right shade)
    105    136     25   2143  % green (bottom right shade)
     64    127    178   1667  % blue (top left shade)
    170    151    191   1380  % purple
     58    132    201   1372  % blue (left shade)
    177    130     45   1242  % orange (bottom wing shade)
    184    123     50   1193  % orange (top wing shade)
    118    114     56    586  % tan (top right)
```

Note that these are not *connected* components, just components with the same color. For a given `mapi`, you can then apply [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to get the connected components for that color.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with encoding the three color arrays (RGB) in a way so that you can merge them into one, two-dimensional array, e.g.

```
2Dimage = I(:,:,1) + 1e3*I(:,:,2) + 1e6*I(:,:,3)
```

that way, you get a unique number for each color: R + 1e3*G + 1e6*B. Note that each channel is encoded with a number in the interval [0, 255].

Now you can go and extract the different color regions from the image using

```
C = unique(2Dimage)
```

to obtain the unique colors you need to look for and then

```
for idx = 1:length(C)
    find(C(idx)==2Dimage)
end
```

to locate the different parts of the image. The color can be readily obtained from the original image *I* at the corresponding locations/indices.

Comment: sorry for late question but how can I locate the different parts of the image after that??

Comment: Let me put it this way: 2Dimage merges the three layers of an image (R, G, and B) to one. Its two-dimensional structure however remains. Thus, you can select the corresponding location in the image using the index you obtained from operations on 2Dimage.